# Kotlin filter memberProperties by present annotation class

Tags: android, reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I've got an extension method running on `Any` type.
On that extension method (where `this` refers to the target instance), I'm trying to filter the memberProperties based on annotation presence.

```
this::class.memberProperties
        .filter{ it.annotations.map { ann -> ann.annotationClass }.contains(ValidComponent::class)}
```

But `it.annotations` is always of size 0

Example of variable declaration on the instance:
`@ValidComponent var x: SomeType = constructorParam.something` or `@ValidComponent lateinit var x: SomeType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with what the annotations are applied to. If you had an annotation with a target of "property", your code would list them just fine:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class ValidComponent
```

[I assume](https://gist.github.com/Zarkopafilis/4eb1c333c85318487562727bbf6bfff8) your annotation has a "field" target instead, in which case you'll have to jump through Java reflection to list the annotations on your properties:

```
this::class.memberProperties
        .filter { property ->
            val fieldAnnotations = property.javaField?.annotations
            fieldAnnotations != null && fieldAnnotations.map { ann -> ann.annotationClass }.contains(ValidComponent::class)
        }
```